# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, error-handling, android-virtual-device

I am running one of my old flutter project in the latest version of android studios and I am facing the issue while running the project please can you help me with this.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\disha.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-
> INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\User_Name.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\c
> om\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              9.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Solution of the error

Answer (score 0):

the error is kind of obvious , As the log says

> "The minCompileSdk (31) is greater than this module's
> compileSdkVersion (android-30)"

which means you are trying to run a project with a minimum android api version of 31 on the emulator or device with the android api version of 30 .

Solution 1 : Reduce the SDK version for the project  (Which is not recommended because you have increased it for a reason )

Solution 2 : Change the emulator or the device for debug .

For more guides on android api version : [check here](https://apilevels.com/)

But you might run into more gradle failures , **AS ALWAYS** , hope not but if you did please make a new issue .

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to update your `build.gradle` file in android/app folder.

Set the following to this values:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
minSdkVersion 19 or (Lower if you want to cater older versions)
targetSdkVersion 31
```